# Issue with R Shiny-server

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, rhel6

I am making changes to shiny app on the R shiny server as the owner of the file. **But I see that changes are not being reflected in the Shiny App.**
I made some changes yesterday and changes were being reflected in the shiny app hosted on the server.
**But I oftentimes run into this issue where changes to R script are not being reflected.
What could be causing this issue?**
The distribution of the linux is RHEL 6.
**Can reloading or restarting the server possibly solve the issue? What else could be other possible solutions?**

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Editing a file does not trigger shiny-server to reread a file nor restart a server process, so it seems likely that it is still operating based on the version of the file as it was when the server started. You'll need to restart the server process explicitly.

Comment: Editing a file does not trigger shiny-server to reread a file **except** for `server.R` and `ui.R`. When I make `source ("ui_server_rshiny/server_rshiny/MySubFile_server_rshiny.R", local = TRUE)` and an update in `MySubFile_server_rshiny.R`, I [touch](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/touch.1.html) `server.R` or add a space into to force shiny server to take this update. (Same in `ui.R` for `MySubFile_ui_rshiny.R`.)